# Custom Class unaccessable from Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, class, asp-classic

I have a class that I've written inside me App_Code directory, I can access the class with all of my normal aspx pages, but I cannot seem to access it from a Web Service that I'm writing.  An example of my class is:

```
public class User
{
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

}
```

and an example of my web service is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


    [WebService(Namespace = "https://example.com")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class example_Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        public example_Service()
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

    }
```

I've tried "using" the the User Class's namespace but it doesn't appear to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the service in the same project as the app_code directory?

Comment: @NikolaiDante, yes, it is in the same project.

Comment: Can you right click the User class in the App_Code directory and make sure the Build Action is set to Compile.

I would assume it is since other pages can access it, but we should make sure.

Comment: @JoshuaLeonard I'm running a WebSite Application, I'm not seeing a Build Action option.  This class has been in use in this application for 10 years, but this is the first time it's been referenced from a Web Service (asmx)

Comment: Your classes are not within any namespaces.

Comment: @Oluwafemi in an attempt to make this work, I added them both to the same namespace, but it didn't work.  I removed the namespace references.

Comment: Use the same namespace as the application and rebuild your solution and try it out.

Comment: Show the name spaces here, also show the exact way you tried using the class from within the webservice class.